# Android: How to change the gravity of an ImageButton placed into a dynamically created layouts

Tags: android, layout, view, gravity, programmatically-created

I have a main dynamically generated `LinearLayout` containing 4 items :
- A `TextView` (dynamic `width`)
- An `ImageView` (static `width`)
- A `TextView` (dynamic `width`)
- An `ImageButton` (static `width`)

The 3 first items should be stuck together and the last one should float on the right of the screen.

```
Name - Rating starts - Number of reviews................. Gmap icon
```

Current :
[image: Current screen]

Expected :
[image: Expected screen]

I have found a solution calculating the width of the generated items and then using that value to set the width of a `layout` containing the items 2 and 3 together.

Comment: Please post your current screen shot and expected one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add a linearlayout instead of your "Gmap icon" and give him following settings

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

and then put your button in this linearLayout

```
layout.addView(myImgButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50sp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="Bussiness 1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#000"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="3sp"
        android:src="@drawable/star"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="3sp"
        android:src="@drawable/star"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="3sp"
        android:src="@drawable/star"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="3sp"
        android:src="@drawable/star"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:src="@drawable/star"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:layout_weight="1.8"
    android:background="#FF0000"

    android:gravity="right"
    >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="25sp"
    android:layout_height="25sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can set visibility of an Imageview as VISABLE/INVISABLE as per your raiting.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to use android:scaleType=""